# How to make image recognition classifier in frontend html,css,js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a HTML,CSS,JS app in which
you can enter you face image, and it will give you all the image
in which your face is present

i want to do this in frontend , pls tell how to implement it ,

I had used face-api and other tools but nothing worked ?

Please tell any resource or code to make it

also it should be very minimal ....

Answer and suggestions to complete it or some code or guidance

Comment: so you want to achieve a facial recognition model only on front end?

Comment: What steps have _you_ taken to investigate this on your own? What didn't work with face-api and "other tools"?  You're essentially asking us to solve all of your problems for you without knowing what they are, and that's not what this site is for. Solutions that you have worked on should be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).